# Mysterious dashes in transcribed interviews for a dissertation

Tags: phd, writing, quotation

I'm editing a dissertation for APA style. I'm encountering a number of transcribed interviews that appear similar to the following:

*I'm very consis-...ah, -consistent...yeah.*

The ellipsis issues aside, this is the first time I've encountered dashes as shown above.

It appears that the dashes are cues for an incomplete word in the first part of the quote and for the complete word in the second part of the quote.

True?

In any case, my inclination is to suggest to the author that they rewrite the text by using brackets, i.e.:

*I'm very consis[tent] . . . yeah.* (If pause and hesitation are not crucial.)

*I'm very consis-(pause) . . . ah, consistent . . . yeah.* (If pause and hesitation are crucial.)

For those of you who are well-versed in APA for dissertation purposes, would you agree with this or suggest a different way of handling it?

Note: I was not successful in looking for guidance in APA 6th edition and at apastyle blog.

Comment: Your example above has a hyphen, but it's an [em-dash that's typically used for this purpose](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Dash&oldid=740454158#Interruption_of_a_speaker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never seen any mention of it in relation to particular academic style guides (I'm sure newspaper/media style guides will say something about it) but the use of dashes to represent abrupt, mid-word (or mid-sentence), disruptions is extremely common. Consequently, I'd imagine that most people reading the dissertation will understand immediately what is intended.

My advice would be to stick with the dashes, but if you wanted to suggest something different then I think both your alternatives are problematic. The first, consis[tent], suffers from the obvious flaw that it assumes what the speaker is going to say, without the transcriber necessarily knowing. For example, how do you know the speaker wasn't going to say "I'm very consistently..." The only thing the transcriber can say for sure (give or take mishearing) that the speaker intended is some word that begins with the syllables "con" and "sis".

The second alternative, consis-(pause) is a little less problematic, but writing (pause) in addition to ellipses is superfluous. As with the dashes, most readers will understand that the ellipses represent pauses, so why potentially confuse matters by providing additional information?

Answer (score 2):

APA style does not cover transcription. You need to ask the author what transcription style they are using (or possibly what software they used). In the absence of author/publisher feedback, you need to pick a [transcription style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcription_(linguistics)). It is not my area of expertise, but the style I have seen most often is [Discourse Transcription](http://www.linguistics.ucsb.edu/projects/transcription/representing).